# VNC connection error

Tags: centos, tigervnc

So, I was following this guide https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-centos-7/ on how to setup a vnc server and I'm at the part where I have to connect to my vnc server via ssh and I'm getting an error.

Error:

`bind: Address already in use`

`channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 5901`

`Could not request local forwarding.`

[image: netStat of connections]

Comment: Please include all essential parts of the guide you used. We encourage users not to source external links as a general rule. Thank you

Comment: Do you get this error when trying to setup the ssh tunnel like in the tutorial?

Comment: @GChuf, I tried vnc viewer on another machine also, I tried `ssh -L 5901:127.0.0.1:5901 -N -f -l username server_ip_address` this command from another machine. And still get this error.

Comment: The port 5901 is already listening on the machine you're trying to setup ssh tunnel on.
I've updated the answer if you want to try to use another port ... meaning you're probably running vnc server on that machine already.
Try the suggestion in my updated answer, but you never answered if VNC connection works without the ssh tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting this error while trying to set up thessh tunnel, it's probably because you're setting up the tunnel on the machine running VNC instead of another machine (where the VNC client is).

The error basicaly means that the port 5901 is already in use on the machine you're trying to setup a tunnel.
You can try changing the port, for example to port 5902, like this:

```
ssh -L 5902:127.0.0.1:5901 -N -f -l username serverIP
```

You can try to connect to VNC without the tunnel as well, to test if your configuration works.

Comment: I did added a rule to my firewalld `sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=5901/tcp --permanent` and disabled selinux and it worked thanks!

Comment: Even though the error wasnt because of the port being used, I hope my answer helped ... If it did, consider upvoting it